# Error moving storage folder

Tags: msmq

I have Windows 2008 R2 server. And I have a brand new msmq service just installed, no old messages in queue.

The default storage folder is `C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage`, I want to move it to `D:\Data\msms\storage`. So I opened Computer Management -> Service and Applications -> Message Queuing, right click on it and selected Property, switched to Storage tab. I typed in D:\Data\msmq\storage in all 3 text boxes. The new folder does not exist at all, when I clicked Apply button system prompted `The folder d:\Data\msmq\storage does not exist. Do you want to create it now?`, and I clicked Yes button. Now the next screen I see is `The folder d:\Data\msmq\storage cannot be created. Error: The system cannot find the path specified.`

Any solution?

Comment: How to check if I am queue owner? There is no queue yet.

Comment: First thing - is D:\ the real root of local physical drive? Secondly, are you logged in as Admin? If you are, try manually creating the d:\Data\msmq\storage folder and assigning it exactly the same access permissions as the existing MSMQ before going through the migration steps.